# Explain the generics used in the Enum declaration

Tags: java, generics, enums

Can someone please explain what this means?

```
Enum<T extends Enum<T>>
```

This seems like a circular definition, and I find it highly confusing to say the least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a [good explanation in the Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ106).

From the end bit:

> To sum it up, the declaration `Enum<E> extends Enum<E>>` can be decyphered
>   as: `Enum` is a generic type that can
>   only be instantiated for its subtypes,
>   and those subtypes will inherit some
>   useful methods, some of which take
>   subtype specific arguments (or
>   otherwise depend on the subtype).

(I do sympathise though - recursively generic declarations are a pain. My protocol buffers port to C# is even worse though: it requires two declarations which each refer to themselves *and* each other... I haven't found a way of simplifying them.)