# What about Enum

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Explain the generics used in the Enum declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648188/explain-the-generics-used-in-the-enum-declaration)

Guys I can't get my head around this:

```
Enum<T extends Enum<T>>;
```

How on earth shall I understand this declaration?

Answer (score 2):

There is an explanation [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ106).